# How to configure Gradle for code generation so that IntelliJ recognises generated java source?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, code-generation

I'm migrating a legacy project to Gradle. One step of the build process is to generate java source code for a proprietary protocol. Unfortunately, when importing the project into IntelliJ, the generated source code is not recognised, so the project does not build with IntelliJ.

I have the following build script (stripped of non-relevant pieces):

```
apply plugin: "base"
apply plugin: "java"

task generate {
    description "Generates java code"
    inputs.files(fileTree("src/codegen/"))
    outputs.dir("${buildDir}/generated-src/")
    // ...
    // codegen
    // ...
}

compileJava {
    source(generate.outputs)
}
```

If I add the following piece, IntelliJ will add the generated source as source, but fail to identify it as *generated*:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "${buildDir}/generated-src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get IntelliJ to recognise the generated sources just as generated sources, so that normal warnings to prevent editing of these classes are shown?

Comment: Did you try out the example given in [this post](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-get-intellij-to-recognize-gradle-generated-sources-dir/16847/5)?

Comment: I'm not sure however it also might be: `srcDirs += ["${buildDir}/generated-src/"]`.

Comment: @Henrik: Now I have, worked like a charm. Thanks! Would you like to add the answer for due credit?

Comment: @PerHuss: Don't mind if I do. :) Two seconds.

Comment: @Opal: The srcDir part works as it is, the source is identified, it's just that I wanted IntelliJ to identify it as generated...

Comment: @PerHuss, sure!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell Idea specifically that the directory contains auto-generated sources, as outlined in [this post](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-get-intellij-to-recognize-gradle-generated-sources-dir/16847/5).

```
apply plugin: "idea"

sourceSets.main.java.srcDir new File(buildDir, '${buildDir}/generated-src/')
idea {
    module {
        // Marks the already(!) added srcDir as "generated"
        generatedSourceDirs += file('${buildDir}/generated-src/')
    }
}
```